# MySQL simple localization

Tags: mysql

Im trying to make some sort of localization in my DB.

For example I have 3 tables(img 1). Languages table contains different languages. Localization table has 3 fields: "id" - id of the string, 'language' - language of the string(id and language are my primary key), 'value' - localized string. tableOne has 'id', 'Col1' and 'Col2' - these fields contain IDs of the localizeable strings.

So after localizing I expect to get one of green tables instead of original(depending on a language parameter).

I've made it this way and it works, but I'd like to know is there any other better way to make it because now I have to create INNER JOIN block for each column, which must  be localized. Im just scared that it will be very very slow.
I tried to create a temporary table to select all records of the required language and then i was doing the same. Inner joins, but searches should be performed only among the records of one language. But its not working because i still had to use multiple inner joins with that temp table which is impossible.

```
SELECT 
    `One`.`id` AS 'id',
    `loc1`.`value` AS 'Col1',
    `loc2`.`value` AS 'Col2'
FROM
    `tableOne` AS `One`
        INNER JOIN
            `localization` AS `loc1` 
        ON `loc1`.`id` = `One.Col1`
        AND `loc1`.`language` = 'en'
        
        INNER JOIN
            `localization` AS `loc2` 
        ON `loc2`.`id` = `One.Col2`
        AND `loc2`.`language` = 'en'
```

[image]
img 1

Comment: I feel like this question is very broad, and can also be opinion based (as people may have different views for how to handle this). Are you having a specific problem? You said what you have is working, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @McAdam331, i would like to avoid that multiple inner joins at least to be able to use this solution(Inner joins, but searches should be performed only among the records of one language. But its not working because i still had to use multiple inner joins with that temp table which is impossible.). Or maybe there is some another ways to replace value of 'tableOne' by matching value from table 'localization'

Comment: I do not know how many records you have in each table. If they it is a relatively small number you may be better finding a way of holding them in memory rather than querying each time.

Comment: it should be a global localization system for whole site. There will be at least  5 languages and at least 1000 values(at start) to localize(small things and large texts). So its not a solution

Comment: Yes, you'll need to join every column needing localization. You'll most likely see much better performance changing the languages.id (and localization.language) to INT...and if you need those 2 character language codes, keeping them as a separate field in the languages table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce the number of `JOINS` needed, try displaying the values in rows instead of columns. You could do so like this:

```
SET @lang := 'en';

SELECT 1, tmp.value
FROM(
  SELECT value
  FROM localization
  WHERE language = @lang AND id IN(543, 345)) tmp;
```

I first set a language parameter, and then I pull all values for that language from the localization table, using the ids inside an IN operator. You'll get results like this:

```
| 1 | one |
| 1 | two |
```

If you have to use the format given in the first table, try doing one inner join where you pull for the specific language and ids like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, 
  CASE WHEN l.id = t1.col1 THEN l.value ELSE null END AS col1Value,
  CASE WHEN l.id = t1.col2 THEN l.value ELSE null END AS col2Value
FROM firstTable t1
JOIN localization l ON l.id IN (t1.col1, t1.col2) AND l.language = @lang;
```

Unfortunately, this won't give you the final solution, it will give you values like:

```
| 1 | 543 | 345 | one  | null |
| 1 | 543 | 345 | null | two  |
```

To wrap those into one column and remove nulls, just add `MAX()`:

This will run a case statement for each column you have, but it will only have one JOIN and looks a little more manageable:

```
SELECT t1.id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN l.id = t1.col1 THEN l.value ELSE null END) AS col1Value,
  MAX(CASE WHEN l.id = t1.col2 THEN l.value ELSE null END) AS col2Value
FROM firstTable t1
JOIN localization l ON l.id IN (t1.col1, t1.col2) AND l.language = @lang
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b14fe/6) example. I don't think the case blocks will bog you down too much, but let me know how this preforms against your actual database.

Comment: yeah, that works fine, but i added GROUP BY t1.id bcuz there were incorrect results with multiple values. Thank you for wasting your time on me. Really helped. Much

Comment: @FiftyStars you're right, I'm sorry I forgot that. In my example I only used one id, so I didn't realize it was a problem. I will edit answer.